# Python subprocess stdout doesn't capture input prompt

Tags: python, subprocess, conda, stdout

I'm using subprocess to spawn a `conda create` command and capture the resulting `stdout` for later use. I also immediately print the `stdout` to the console so the user can still see the progress of the subprocess:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('conda create -n env1 python', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    sys.stdout.write(line.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

This works fine until half way through the execution when the `conda create` requires user input: it prompts `Proceed (n/y)?` and waits for the user to input an option. However, the code above doesn't print the prompt and instead just waits for input "on a blank screen". Once an input is received the prompt is printed *afterwards* and then execution continues as expected.

I assume this is because the input somehow blocks the prompt being written to `stdout` and so the `readline` doesn't receive new data until after the input block has been lifted.

Is there a way I can ensure the input prompt is printed before the subprocess waits for user input? Note I'm running on Windows.

Comment: Note that ``readline`` actually looks for an entire line, up to the end-of-line character ``\n``. A ``Proceed (n/y)? y`` prompt does *not* output an entire line but expects input (the ``y``)  inline.

Comment: You raise a good point. Is it likely a simple fix using `read` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm sure pexpect would have worked in this case, I decided it would be overkill. Instead I used MisterMiyagi's insight and replaced `readline` with `read`.

The final code is as so:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('conda create -n env1 python', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while p.poll() is None:
    sys.stdout.write(p.stdout.read(1).decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note the `read(1)` as just using `read()` would block the while loop until an EOF is found. Given no EOF is found before the input prompt, nothing will be printed at all! In addition, `flush` is called which ensures the text written to `sys.stdout` is actually visible on screen.

Comment: proc.stdout.isatty() gives False, and proc.stdout.writable() as well. Why is it that much complicated ? proc.stdout.read(1) get stuck in a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case I recommend using [pexpect](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/).  *stdin != stdout*

Example use case where it conditionally sends to *stdin* on prompts on *stdout*

```
def expectgit(alog):
    TMPLOG = "/tmp/pexpect.log"
    cmd = f'''
ssh -T git@github.com ;\
echo "alldone" ;
'''
    with open(TMPLOG, "w") as log:
        ch = pexpect.spawn(f"/bin/bash -c \"{cmd}\"", encoding='utf-8', logfile=log)
        while True:
            i = ch.expect(["successfully authenticated", "Are you sure you want to continue connecting"])
            if i == 0:
                alog.info("Git all good")
                break
            elif i == 1:
                alog.info("Fingerprint verification")
                ch.send("yes\r")
        ch.expect("alldone")
        i = ch.expect([pexpect.EOF], timeout=5)
        ch.close()
        alog.info("expect done - EOF")

    with open(TMPLOG) as log:
        for l in log.readlines():
            alog.debug(l.strip())
```

Comment: This works pretty slick for getting the output to the screen. 

How to accomplish capturing the user response for sending back to the subprocess...?