# Passing input to subprocess popen at runtime based on stdout string

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdin

I am trying to run following code

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args=cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while process.poll() is None:
   stdoutput = process.stdout.readline()
   print(stdoutput.decode())
   if '(Y/N)' in stdoutput.decode():
       process.communicate(input=b'Y\n')
```

this cmd argument runs for a few minutes after which it prompts for a confirmation, but the `process.communicate` is not working, neither is `process.stdin.write()`

How do I send input string 'Y' to this running process when it prompts for confirmation

Comment: Can you share what is the value of `cmd` that you are executing?

Comment: its a custom written exe with some command line arguments, which after few minutes asks for confirmation, and then proceeds execution further

Answer (score 1):

Per [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) on `Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)`:

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`.

Please try that, and if it's not sufficient, do indicate what the symptom is.

Comment: i updated the program, but still this doesnt work, the script/process ends the moment it encounters `popen.communicate()`, there's no error, but the prompt fails the process terminates

Comment: I'd think up many hypotheses about what could be going wrong and a way to test each. Maybe this code is not properly detecting the "Y/N" prompt, so print something before it calls `process.communicate()`. Maybe the subprocess is not receiving the input text or didn't get the newline or something, so make it print the input text or set a breakpoint in it, or substitute a small test command. Maybe the subprocess is failing for another reason like OutOfMemory -- so print the `process.poll()` return code and the `process.communicate()` return tuple. Also see @NielGodfreyPonciano's answer.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the answer from @Jerry101, if the subprocess that you are calling is a python script that uses the [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), be aware that as documented:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output **without a trailing newline**.

Thus if you perform [readline()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) as in `process.stdout.readline()`, it would hang there waiting for the new line `\n` character as documented:

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (`\n`) is left at the end of the string

A quick fix is append the newline `\n` when requesting the `input()` e.g. `input("(Y/N)\n")` instead of just `input("(Y/N)")`.

Related question:

- [Python subprocess stdout doesn't capture input prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129698/python-subprocess-stdout-doesnt-capture-input-prompt)