# Python subprocess output stream stdout.read hangs forever for input prompt

Tags: python, stdout, popen

I am trying to run a subprocess with Popen, and at a time it asks for an input prompt without any `EOF`, so `stdout.read()` blocks the while loop until an `EOF` is found, like forever because there will be none.

I am unable to detect if we are in an input prompt coming next via

- `proc.stdout.isatty()` it stays at False
- `proc.stdout.writable()` it stays at False

main1.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

proc = Popen(["python3", "main2.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
def read_until_it_finishes():
    while proc.poll() is None:
        if proc.stdout.isatty() is True: # <-- Why this line isn't it detecting we are in a input prompt ?
            break
        if proc.stdout.writable() is True: # <-- Why this line isn't it detecting we are in a input prompt ?
            break
        line =  proc.stdout.read(1).decode(sys.stdout.encoding) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137801/10294022
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()

read_until_it_finishes()
proc.stdin.write(b"My name is Catwoman\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
```

main2.py

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Hello my name is Batman\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write("I am awesome\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
name = input('And you what is your name:')
sys.stdout.write(name)
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.close()
```

Then run

```
python3 main1.py
```

Would you please help me ?

Comment: You have to change lines order: `proc.stdin.write(b"My name is Catwoman\n")` → `proc.stdin.flush()` → `read_until_it_finishes()`

Comment: I don't want to do this, I wanna see the question before writing the answer.

Comment: There really isn't any other way ? see the input question, think about it, then stdin.write() ?

Comment: what do you mean by `think`? Here is no `think` time even between `read_until_it_finishes()` and `proc.stdin.write(b"My name is Catwoman\n")`. It will be run as solid-single piece of code

Comment: I mean I am gonna do a websocket chat with a terminal subprocess, I need the guy to see the question before he answers it. And you what is your name: ???

Comment: Your example is little bit unclear for me, but I added an example with interactive `think`-able part. Does it what you want to know?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to pass `stdin` and print `stdout` between applications:

- runner.py:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

proc = Popen(["python", "app.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
def read_until_it_finishes():
    while proc.poll() is None:
        char = proc.stdout.read(1).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char == '>':
            name = input('')
            proc.stdin.write(name.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
            proc.stdin.write(b'\n')
            proc.stdin.flush()

read_until_it_finishes()
```

- app.py

```py
print('Hello, I`m a bot')

while True:
    name = input('What is your name (or print exit to exit)>')
    if name == 'exit':
        print('bye bye')
        break
    print(f'Hello {name}')
```

- output:

```
Hello, I`m a bot
What is your name (or print exit to exit)>a
Hello a
What is your name (or print exit to exit)>b
Hello b
What is your name (or print exit to exit)>c
Hello c
What is your name (or print exit to exit)>exit
bye bye
```

---

#### Extra question:

> you are using a special character char == '>' to break the loop, in order to avoid using stdout.read again. Actually the app as subprocess I am running doesn't use this kind of character, and I can't edit this app

#### Extra answer:

If you don't able to expect command line prompt line and don't know specific prompt character that can be used as break point, you may try to switch between input and output by using `Timer`:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Timer
import sys

SECONDS = 3

proc = Popen(["python", "app.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

def run_input():
    if proc.poll() is None:
        name = input('')
        proc.stdin.write(name.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
        proc.stdin.write(b'\n')
        proc.stdin.flush()

def read_until_it_finishes():
    timer = Timer(SECONDS, run_input)
    timer.start()
    while proc.poll() is None:
        try:
            char = proc.stdout.read(1).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        finally:
            timer.cancel()
            timer = Timer(SECONDS, run_input)
            timer.start()

read_until_it_finishes()
```

In this case `runner.py` will be waiting for `input` every 3 seconds (`SECONDS` variable). But this logic is ineffective because:

1. Long latency between `inputs`. Even if bot is answering in 1 second you have to wait for 3 seconds until to be able do input
2. If bot is answering longer than 3 seconds the answer print will be stopped at the middle until next input

But here is no other way (at least I can't see other way) to determine if `app.py` is waiting for input or just busy and running some background operations.

Comment: I get it, you are using a special character char == '>' to break the loop, in order to avoid using stdout.read again. Actually the app as subprocess I am running doesn't use this kind of character, and I can't edit this app.

Comment: I am trying to run something like this https://github.com/tomtom94/GGGPPPTTTbackv2/blob/master/main.py

Comment: I gave you one good point for you Answer. Reply to me via my github repository if ever you want, not here.

Comment: Many thanks, it works like a charm when you spot a special character to break the while loop. Cheers happy day for you.

Comment: @ThomasAumaitre I added extra solution based on timer to be able break loop without specific characters (like `>` in previous example). But this solution is not effective and I don't recommend to use it. According to your GitHub you found better one.

Comment: Yes I use the special character solution like you, I had to change the source program. The regex character I am targeting are the following ": ]" I already tried whith smileys but too complicated.