# Don't manage to launch subprocess with its own memory space in Python

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I am trying to launch a Python program as a subprocess for each web connection through a Flask server.

In fact, I am trying to launch a process to run AutoGPT. It works but each launched AutoGPT process seems to have the same memory space.

```
from subprocess import Popen, call, PIPE
import sys
import re
import io

class AutoGPT:
    cache_running_process = []
    def __getCache__(self, sid):
        for e in AutoGPT.cache_running_process: # https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054570
            if e.sid == sid:
                return e
        return None

    def __init__(self, socketio, sid):
        self.socketio = socketio
        cache = self.__getCache__(sid)
        if cache is not None:
            self.sid = cache.sid
            self.proc = cache.proc
        else:
            self.proc = Popen(["./run.sh"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd="./Auto-GPT", start_new_session=True)
            self.sid = sid
            print('current sid :'+sid)
            self.cache_running_process.append(self)

    def check_tag_at_the_end(self, line_target):
        line_splitted = line_target.split()
        if len(line_splitted) < 2:
            return None
        return re.search("\: \]$", line_splitted[-2] + " " + line_splitted[-1])

    def read_until_it_finishes(self):
        line = ""
        colorama = False
        while self.proc.poll() is None:
            char =  self.proc.stdout.read(1) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137801/10294022
            char_utf8 = char.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            line += char_utf8
            if self.check_tag_at_the_end(line) is not None:
                break
            if colorama == True and char == bytes('m', 'utf-8'):
                # We are finishing with ANSI characters for color text in terminal https://github.com/tartley/colorama#recognised-ansi-sequences
                colorama = False
            else:
                if colorama == False and char != bytes('\x1b', 'utf-8'):
                    if char == bytes('\n', 'utf-8'):
                        self.socketio.emit('my_response', 
                            {'data': "<br />"}, namespace='/test')
                    else:
                        self.socketio.emit('my_response', 
                            {'data': char_utf8}, namespace='/test')
                else:
                    # We are starting with ANSI characters for color text in terminal
                    colorama = True

    def write(self, message):
        self.proc.stdin.write(bytes(message + "\n", 'utf-8'))
        self.proc.stdin.flush()
        self.read_until_it_finishes()

    def close(self):
        self.proc.terminate()
        cache = self.__getCache__(self.sid)
        index = self.cache_running_process.index(cache)
        del self.cache_running_process[index]
```

Then, when I give the name TOTO to the first process and TITI to the second, the first process, unfortunately, gets the TOTO name!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it use a shared memory segment or something weird like that?

Comment: How do you establish that they use the "same memory space"? A proper [mre] of what I think you seem to be asking does not seem to reproduce the problem: https://ideone.com/KOYsND

Comment: Hi,
I think it was an error from me. In fact there were 2 different process. It was the stdout of the two process which were mixed.